# Docker build error with Flask app MySQLdb

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm just getting started with Docker, so I decided I'd try to create a simple flask API app.

The problem is, I keep getting various errors depending on what I try to do to fix them.

My `requirements.txt`:

```
Flask
MySQL-python
bleach
bcrypt
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
MAINTAINER Caleb Hester "naclcaleb@gmail.com"
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT ["python2.7"]
CMD ["api.py"]
```

I get this error: EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found

I tried a few things, including adding a `apt-get -y build-dep python-mysqldb`, but when I do that, I get an error about needing to add some URIs to my `sources.list`, and something about locales and `C.UTF-8`.

I'm very confused here.

Does anyone know what the proper docker file would be?

UPDATE:

After adding `libmysqlclient-dev` to my `apt-get install`, the MySQLdb error goes away, but now I'm getting this error for cffi:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-JrzOzV/python2.7-2.7.15~rc1=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DUSE__THREAD -DHAVE_SYNC_SYNCHRONIZE -I/usr/include/ffi -I/usr/include/libffi -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c c/_cffi_backend.c -o build/temp.linux-armv7l-2.7/c/_cffi_backend.o
    c/_cffi_backend.c:15:10: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
     #include <ffi.h>
              ^~~~~~~
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Update:

I fixed this by adding `libffi-dev` to my `apt-get install`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be missing the mysql deb package.

Try appending `libmysqlclient-dev` to the line

```
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential
```

so that you now have

```
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of the first error, but now I get this: `error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc' failed with exit status 1
`

Comment: @CalebH. not sure of the reason for that - might be better to ask that as a separate question